# Quirky output python

Tags: python

Please explain below, I think it should have printed True or False since these are boolean expressions. And why it's printing 2 1 and then 1 2

```
print 1 and 2
print 2 and 1
print 1 or 2
print 2 or 1
```

output:

```
2
1
1
2
```

Comment: This is clearly explained in [the Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/boolean.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why you think the result must be a boolean type ?

from python wiki :

> The expression [**x and y**](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#and) first evaluates x; if x is false, its **value** is returned; otherwise, y is evaluated and the resulting **value** is returned.
>
> The expression **x or y** first evaluates x; if x is true, its **value** is returned; otherwise, y is evaluated and the resulting **value** is returned.

Note that neither **and** nor **or** restrict the value and type they return to False and True, but rather return the last evaluated argument. This is sometimes useful, e.g., if `s` is a string that should be replaced by a default value if it is empty, the expression `s or 'foo'` yields the desired value. Because not has to invent a value anyway, it does not bother to return a value of the same type as its argument, so e.g., `not 'foo'` yields False, not `''`.